# Squaring application in java

Tags: java, drjava

New to programming here. I need to write application that does the following...
[Squaring application instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VmWy.pngThe)

The code I have so far follows. I am running into a problem where my code will not read from negative integers to strings and properly prompt the user to enter valid data. I believe I need to nest my loops but am having trouble doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Squaring {

    public static int getValidInt(int greaterThan, Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer greater than " + greaterThan + ":" );
        int input; 

        while ( !scan.hasNextInt() ) { 
            String garbage = scan.next();
            scan.nextLine(); 
            System.out.println(garbage + " is not valid input."); 
            System.out.println("Enter an integer greater than " + greaterThan + ":" );
        }

        while ( !((input = scan.nextInt()) > greaterThan )) { 
            int garbage = input; 
            System.out.println(garbage + " is not greater than 1.");
            System.out.println("Enter an integer greater than " + greaterThan + ":" );
        }

        return input; 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 1 ;
        int total = 0;
        a = getValidInt(a,scan);
        int b = a; 
        System.out.println(a);
        long n = a; 
        while ( n < 1000000 ) {
            System.out.println(n*n);
            n = n * n; 
            total = total + 1; 
        }
        System.out.println(b + " exceeded 1,000,000 after " + total + " squarings.") ;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you allowed to use try-catch for input validation?

Comment: this won't answer your question, but just a heads up you may want to change this line: `System.out.println(garbage + " is not greater than 1.");` to this: `System.out.println(garbage + " is not greater than " + greaterThan + ".");`

Comment: We haven't learned try-catch yet but yes i am open to all solutions.

Comment: I don't see your code doing anything wrong

Answer (score 1):

Without any try-catch:

```
public static int getValidInt(int greaterThan, Scanner scan) {
    int input = 0;
    boolean valid = false;

    while (!valid) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer greater than " + greaterThan + ":");

        if (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
            String garbage = scan.next();
            System.out.println(garbage + " is not valid input.");
        } else {
            input = scan.nextInt();

            if (input <= greaterThan) {
                System.out.println(input + " is not greater than " + greaterThan);
            } else {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return input;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = getValidInt(1, scan);
    System.out.println(a);

    int total = 0;
    long n = a;

    while ( n < 1000000 ) {
        n = n * n;
        System.out.println(n);
        total++;
    }

    System.out.println(a + " exceeded 1,000,000 after " + total + " squarings.") ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the following:

```
public static int getValidInt(int greaterThan, Scanner scan) {

    int number = greaterThan;

    do {
        while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
            String garbage = scan.next();
            System.out.println(garbage + " is not valid input.");
        }
        number = scan.nextInt();

        if (number < greaterThan) {
            System.out.println("input is: " + number + " minimum is: " + greaterThan);
        }

    } while (number < greaterThan);

    return number;
}
```

---

It has a `do while` loop which makes sure `number` cannot be smaller than `greaterThan`, if it is it will do the `while` loop again. 
Inside the `do while` loop is another loop which tells the user that their input is garbage, and will continue doing so until a number is inserted.